# Flutter Websocket Secure error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch

Tags: flutter, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am using secure websocket in Flutter connect to server,  my server side is using self-signed certificate. in flutter clent, I store the trusted `CA.pem`  in local assets.  and load it to verify server certificate. my code is like this:

```dart
void main() async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/data/ca-cert.pem');
  runApp( child: const App());
}
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  final ByteData data;

  MyHttpOverrides({required this.data});

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    final SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext()..
    setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List())
    Log().i("cert.pre=" + data.buffer.asUint8List().toString());
    return super.createHttpClient(clientContext);
  
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
WebSocketChannelException: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:359))
```

Most answers on internet are like this

```dart
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
@override
HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
return super.createHttpClient(context)
  ..badCertificateCallback =
      (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true; }}
```

but I would say this is not a safe solution for product environment. because you just accept any untrusted certificate.
I also try kotlin version in native android runing on same deivce. it has no issues with below codes:

```kotlin
if (address.indexOf("wss") == 0) {
    var sslContext: SSLContext? = null
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
        val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val instream = context.assets.open("ca-cert.pem") 
        val ca = cf.generateCertificate(instream)
        val trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
        trustStore.load(null, null)
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)
        val trustManagerFactory =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore)
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: CertificateException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: KeyStoreException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: KeyManagementException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val factory: SSLSocketFactory? = sslContext?.socketFactory
    client.setSocketFactory(factory!!)
}
try {
    client.connectBlocking()
} catch (e: InterruptedException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: The error says that the hostname doesn't match. Have you checked that the server cert matches the hostname that you are using in the URL to open the connection?

Comment: I can get the host from     ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
  return true;
} the host in the callback is exactly the same as my conenction URL both are 192.168.1.5 .  or do you know which field represent the hostname in certificatre?  
It is werid why it works fine with the kotlin codes?

Comment: The hostname in a certificate is the CN field of the Subject. An IP address is *not* a valid hostname. Create a new certificate for the server with a real hostname, sign it with the same CA and try that.

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHeap after I regenerated the server certificate with CN=192.168.1.5, It works fine.  my case is only within ethernet. no hostname just IP address. maybe I need consider regular expression in CN field because ip address is dynamic in ethernet.

Comment: it seems it's not possible to deactivate checking hostname in flutter. in android we can use HostnameVerifier. And it also seems that is possible to do it in iOS with a SecPolicyCreateSSL.  I would like to write a plugin.

Comment: Yes you can, with the `badCertificateCallback`. In `HostnameVerifier`  you override `verify(String hostname, ...)` and manually check the host name. In Dart you get the hostname in the bad cert callback and can perform the same manual check.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks, I think this is somehow a solution. but not good as other languages.
it seems `badCertificateCallback`  will be called when any bad certificate comes. no mater   
CA trusted certificate(with hostname mismatch) or untrusted certificate. I need to verify something in the callback anyway. I think its better to provide an APi to deactivate checking hostname, In Python, we can use `ssl_context.check_hostname = False`,  in android we can use `public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }`